# is it possibe to use crossover function within if else block under pinescipt language

Tags: pine-script

I am extremely new to Programming and determined to build a crossover alert for EMA with value of 5 and VWAP with 5 minute timeframe. I amd trying to do this using If else statement using crossover.

But of no luck. I tried to build something like this and landed here.

// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © Shailendra

//@version=5

```
indicator("EMA5 & VWAP Crossover Alert", overlay= true)

// Calculate values
emaValue = ta.ema(close,5)
vwapValue = ta.vwap(hlc3)

//plotting on map
plot(emaValue, title="EMA",color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(vwapValue, title="VWAP", color=color.black, linewidth=2)


buyNow=ta.crossover(emaValue,vwapValue)
sellNow= ta.crossover(vwapValue,emaValue)

alertcondition(buyNow,title="EMA5 Crossed VWAP", message ="BUY !! BUY!! BUY!!")
alertcondition(sellNow,title="VWAP Crossed EMA", message ="SELL !! SELL!! SELL!!")
```

Answer (score 1):

alertcondition will not send any alert. You will have to use actual alert call inside if to send alerts like below

```
//@version=5

indicator("EMA5 & VWAP Crossover Alert", overlay= true)

// Calculate values
emaValue = ta.ema(close,5)
vwapValue = ta.vwap(hlc3)

//plotting on map
plot(emaValue, title="EMA",color=color.green, linewidth=2)
plot(vwapValue, title="VWAP", color=color.black, linewidth=2)


buyNow=ta.crossover(emaValue,vwapValue)
sellNow= ta.crossover(vwapValue,emaValue)

if buyNow
    alert("EMA5 Crossed VWAP, BUY !! BUY!! BUY!!", alert.freq_all)
if sellNow
    alert("VWAP Crossed EMA, SELL !! SELL!! SELL!!", alert.freq_all)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help in this. I am trying to make a custom function, wherein i can pass the symbol name as argument and get the result.

I wish to apply these alert on my wishlist. How to do that ?